# How do I disable the fade in / out animation of SnackBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

Hi I'm showing a SnackBar with buttons on it. When user press a button it should highlight that button. Thus I made it show a new SnackBar where that particular button is pressed. 
However, whenever the user tap on the button the new SnackBar has this fade in animation which makes it look like a glitch.

So how can I disable this fade in and out animation in a SnackBar?

Thanks

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide.none, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
    content: _getButtons(),
  ));
```

Then when a button clicked, it removes the SnackBar:

```
Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
```

Then show the above SnackBar again with a new settings to the buttons.

Actually these codes probably doesn't help the question. What is important is how do we access the SnackBar's Animation and disable it?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Snackbar has 'animation' property. Did you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `animationController` and set it's value to `zero`, and attach this controller to the `animation` prop of `Snackbar`

```
late AnimationController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }
```

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
   behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
   animation: controller,
   content: const Text("Details Updated Successfully"),
   duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
   action: SnackBarAction(
   label: 'Undo',
   onPressed: () {
     controller.reverse();
   }
  )
));
```

Answer (score -1):

The current behavior of SnackBar is it slides from the bottom-up when it's displayed, and slides back down when dismissed. An easy way of managing this is by creating your own "SnackBar". To omit any animation when displayed, update the screen displaying the Widget. Then doing it in reverse to dismiss.

```dart
bool showDialog = false;

...

showDialog ? 
  Row(
    children: [
      Text('...'),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Dismiss'),
        onPressed: () {
          setState((){
            showDialog = false;
          });
        }
      ),
    ],
  ) 
  :
  SizedBox(), // Return empty Widget if hidden
```

Updating showDialog to true should display the Widget

```dart
setState((){
  showDialog = true;
});
```

Aside from this, you can also explore working with SnackBar's [animation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/animation.html) property.

Comment: Can you give example using Snackbar's animation property ? I don't find it in docs